# Removing multiple consecutive words separated with whitespace

Tags: regex, perl

In the code below the pattern `/ man /` matches twice consecutively. So when I substitute that pattern only the first occurence is matched but the second occurence is not matched.

As I understand the problem the first pattern itself matches until the start of second pattern(i.e, the space after man is the end of first pattern and also the start of first pattern). So second pattern is not matched. How to match this pattern globally when it occurs consecutively.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#my $name =" man sky man ";  #this works

my $name =" man man sky";    #this does'nt
$name =~s/ man / nam /g;    #expected= 'nam nam sky'
print $name,"\n";
```

Comment: So, `"man man sky"` should result in `"man nam sky"`, right? Please precise the question.

Comment: This looks like a XY problem. If you want to match whole words, use the `\b` assertion.

Comment: So, `"man man sky"` should result in `"man nam sky"`, right? Please precise the question.

Comment: `man man sky` should become `nam nam sky`

Comment: Then you should use [`s/(?<!\S)man(?!\S)/nam/g`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51204265/3832970) (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1wP3bc/2)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex is eating up characters which it matches. So, to avoid this, you should use lookahead and lookbehind to match it in this case. Check [`perlre`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)

```
$name =~ s/(?<=\s)man(?=\s)/nam/g;
```

Quoting from `perlre`

**Look Ahead:**

> ```
> (?=pattern)
> A zero-width positive lookahead assertion. For example, /\w+(?=\t)/ matches 
> a word followed by a tab, without including the tab in $&.
> ```

**Look Behind:**

> ```
> (?<=pattern) \K A zero-width positive lookbehind assertion. For
> example, /(?<=\t)\w+/ matches a word that follows a tab, without
> including the tab in $& . Works only for fixed-width lookbehind.
> ```

Comment: More efficient: `s/ man(?= )/ nam/g` or `s/\s\Kman(?=\s)/nam/g`

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want to replace `man` in between whitespace characters or start/end of string.

In this case, you may use two approaches, with positive lookarounds containing alternation operator checking for string boundaries and/or whitespaces, or negative lookarounds checking for the non-whitespace chars on  both ends of the search word.

Use either of the two:

```
$name =~ s/(?<=^|\s)man(?=\z|\s)/nam/g;
$name =~ s/(?<!\S)man(?!\S)/nam/g;
```

From the point of view of efficiency, the second option is better since alternation is a bit "expensive".

The `(?<=^|\s)` positive lookbehind matches a location in string that is preceded with start of string (`^`) or (`|`) a whitespace (`\s`) and the `(?=$|\s)` positive lookahead makes sure there is a whitespace or end of string (`$`) immediately after `man`.

The `(?<!\S)` negative lookbehind matches a location in string that is not immediately preceded with a non-whitespace char, i.e. if there is a non-whitespace char there will be no match), and `(?!\S)` negative lookahead asserts there is no non-whitespace right after `man`.

See more details about [*Lookaround Assertions* at `perlre`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions).

Comment: `$` means `(?=\n?\z)`, so `(?=$|\s)` means `(?=\n?\z|\s)`, which is a complicated way of writing `(?=\s|\z)`

Comment: Note that your substitutions are nearly identical to `s/\bman\b/nam/g`, which is probably close enough for the OP.

Comment: @ikegami If the goal is to match before the whitespace or *the very end of string*, then yes, `\z` should be used (`chomp` would relieve the problem). The `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` lookarounds define *whitespace* boundaries rather than *word boundaries*, so although they may look similar, they are quite  different: `\bman\b` matches `man` in `man-of-war`, but `(?<!\S)man(?!\S)` won't.

Comment: Re "*If the goal is*", No, `(?=$|\s)` and `(?=\s|\z)` are equivalent as I said

Comment: Re "*They are quite different*", I did say they were different

Comment: @ikegami :) I understand *nearly identical* as something "not-so-different" :)

Comment: ...yet still different